# Searching nested document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a data as below:

```
[
    { id: 1, name: { en: "Thing", ru: "...", fr: "..." }, rating: 5 },
    { id: 2, name: { en: "Another thing", ru: "...", fr: "..." }, rating: 2 },
    { id: 3, name: { en: "A nother", ru: "...", fr: "..." }, rating: 4 },
]
```

where `name` field has 3 sub-fields, each represents a localized string.

I'd like search through the `name` field, but I don't want to specify the `locale`.

How can I do it?

---

PS: I can do the following:

```
{ 'name.en': { $in: [/nother/i] } }
```

which gives me item 2 and 3.

Comment: did you try this? `{$or:['name.en':{$in:[query]},'name.ru':{$in:[query]},'name.fr':{$in:[query]}]}`

Comment: yes, I can do that too but it's not scalable. what if schema has 20 languages? that's why...

Comment: It seems a misconception. Why would you search something over several locales? Normally, the systems restrict information from a specific locale. So, if you are building something to be used in real world, I guess this feature is gonna mess your system.

Comment: i have `lang` info that is sent by the client to the server and i might use it later for the sake of server performance if needed. for now, i'm just looking into possibility whether i can provide a multilingual search or not.